# My fridge door was left cracked open over night

Tags: dairy

My fridge door was left open over  night with the fridge light on.  Is my dairy products safe to eat?

Comment: What temperature did it reach & for how long? Did the milk go lumpy? Does it smell 'off'?

Comment: I tested this with my refridgerator and discovered that I had to open the door four (4) inches before the light went on. Four inches! And my door automatically closed at that point. So, just how open was your door?

Comment: What's the room temperature overnight? Is the light a traditional bulb or LED? (the latter delivers much more heat).  Hard cheese [will be fine](https://www.foodprotection.org/publications/food-protection-trends/archive/2006-10storage-temperatures-necessary-to-maintain-cheese-safety/) and pasteurised milk will normally spoil detectably